# Spring boot Jackson Deserializer for ZonedDateTime Not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have overridden configuration for objectMapper.

```
@Bean
  @Primary
  public ObjectMapper serializingObjectMapper() {
    return getObjectMapper();
  }

  public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class,
        new LocalDateTimeSerializer(dateTimeFormatter));
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class,
        new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(dateTimeFormatter));

    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class,
        new LocalDateSerializer(dateFormatter));
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class,
        new LocalDateDeserializer(dateFormatter));

    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, ZonedDateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class, InstantDeserializer.ZONED_DATE_TIME);

    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    return objectMapper;
  }
```

I have LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime. LocalDateTime correctly coming. But ZonedDateTimeis not coming in ISO format

```
"zonedIdField": 1658829622.000000000,
"localDateTimeField": "2022-12-15T15:35:27",
```

Am I missing something. ZonedDateTimeis coming as number

Comment: You shouldn't need that configuration at all, that should all work out-of-the-box if the java time module is on the classpath.

Comment: @M.Deinum, if we want to customize using a formatter, so I added it.

Comment: I don't see any difference from the ISO format but that could be me. Nonetheless if you are using the default serializers you should also disable the write dates as timestamp feature (which is used by default but disabled by Spring Boot). However as I stated I don't see any added value in what you have here over the ISO formats.

Comment: The autoconfigured `ObjectMapper` should work fine. Why are you creating your own one?

Comment: @M.Deinum, I just want to convert the dates as per needed format, is there any way to do it with out this.

Comment: The formats you show here are the default ISO formats, so as I stated before I don't get your configuration. Your configuration does actually disable parts of the auto-configuration of Spring Boot. Hence if your formats are the same as the ISO ones just remove this configuration and it should work out-of-the-box. If the formats are different you can specify the formats through `spring.jackson.date-format` or by registering a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`.